# Mongodb error : The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregation explain

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the mongodb 3.5.5 with mongoose 4.9.8 and the Node.js version is 7.10, when I publish my app to production server, the error was happened, but in my develop environment is work.

How can I fix them?

The error message:

```
{ MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregation explain
     at Function.MongoError.create (/data/deploy/aaa/webapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
     at /data/deploy/aaa/webapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:489:72
     at authenticateStragglers (/data/deploy/aaa/webapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:435:16)
     at Connection.messageHandler (/data/deploy/aaa/webapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:5)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/data/deploy/aaa/webapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:321:22)
     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
     at TCP.onread (net.js:561:20)
   name: 'MongoError',
   message: 'The \'cursor\' option is required, except for aggregation explain',
   ok: 0,
   errmsg: 'The \'cursor\' option is required, except for aggregation explain',
   code: 9,
   codeName: 'FailedToParse' }
```

js code:

```
  articleLikeSchema.statics.sumById = function ({id = ''} = {}) {
    return this.model('ArticleLike').aggregate([
      { $match: { id: id } },
      { $group: { _id: '$id', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ]).then(sum => {
      if (!sum || sum.length === 0) return Promise.resolve({count: 0})
      else return Promise.resolve(sum[0])
    })
  }
```

The Mongoose execute command:

```
Mongoose: articlelikes.aggregate([ { '$match': { id: '1494606935' } }, { '$group': { _id: '$id', count: { '$sum': 1 } } } ], {})
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442588/mongoose-aggregation-query-fails-in-jest-mockgoose-test-works-elsewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose aggregation query fails in Jest/Mockgoose test, works elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442588/mongoose-aggregation-query-fails-in-jest-mockgoose-test-works-elsewhere)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla)

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide cursor option for aggregate calls which is changed in Mongo 3.6

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate

So adding {cursor:{}} to you aggregate call should resolve this problem:

```
  articleLikeSchema.statics.sumById = function ({id = ''} = {}) {
    return this.model('ArticleLike').aggregate([
          { $match: { 
                id: id 
              } 
          },
          { $group: { 
                _id: '$id', 
                count: { $sum: 1 } 
              } 
          }
        ], 
        { cursor:{} }
    ).then(sum => {
      if (!sum || sum.length === 0) return Promise.resolve({count: 0})
      else return Promise.resolve(sum[0])
    })
  }
```

Comment: I tried to use Mongo 3.5 and it failed with the same error. 3.4 worked.

Comment: @iurisilvio - Do you mean Mongo 3.6?

Comment: No, @Himanshu 3.5. Did not investigated, becausey production mongo is 3.4, I just changed my local version.

Comment: @iurisilvio - Stable release is either 3.4 or 3.6. Not sure why did you select 3.5. The change above was for 3.6 which might not be supported in 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

With Mongoose 3.6, Mongoose 4.13.20, Node 6.11.0 + "callback approach", I had to do:

```
return this.model('ArticleLike').aggregate([
      { $match: { id: id } },
      { $group: { _id: '$id', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ]).exec(function (err, results) {
      // ...
    })
```

Without need to add a parameter containing `{ cursor: {} }`.