# The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I m upgrading from mongo 2.6 to 3.6 its give me error on creating new record.

```
admin = User.new(email: "Administrator@gmail.com", password: "admin123", role: "Admin", status: "approved")`
admin.save`
```

I'm using `mongoid 4.0.2`

> failed with error 9: "The 'cursor' option is required, except for
>   aggregate with the explain argument"

Comment: How are you creating the new record?

Comment: I m updating the question please check

Comment: Update your mongoose version to 5.x... Check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla

Comment: I have upgraded mongoose to 5.1.6 but still have same error