# MongoDB aggregation $lookup and cursor and pipeline errors

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run this aggregation to create a persistent join with Mongoose against MongoDB:

```
await HourLog.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'timeentries',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'hourLog',
    as: 'timeEntries'
  }
},
  { $out: 'hourlogs' }
]);
```

With Mongo version 3.6.6 and Mongoose version 4.8.7

I get this error:

```
Error: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

I tried adding the cursor option:

```
  await HourLog.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'timeentries',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'hourLog',
    as: 'timeEntries'
  }
},
  { $out: 'hourlogs' }
], { $cursor: { } });
```

But I get a new error:

```
Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Update your [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla) version to 5.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla)