# Using Cursor() in Mongo Aggregates with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I recently updated mongo on my dev environment to take advantage of new functionality (Mongod 1.4 --> 4.0).  Now all of my existing aggregate queries are returning an error:

---

> { [MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate
>   with the explain argument]   name: 'MongoError',   ok: 0,   errmsg:
>   'The \'cursor\' option is required, except for aggregate with the
>   explain argument',   code: 9,   codeName: 'FailedToParse' }

---

I know I should be able to add a 'cursor()' element to the pipeline definition (my expected return data is small), but I can't seem to get the syntax right, or find a good example online using Node/Mongoose syntax.  My best guess is to add the cursor as follows:

=====================================================

```
ParticipantActivityLog.aggregate([
    {   $match: {
            "$and": [
                {logDate :{$gte : new Date(postDataObj.strtDt),$lt : new Date(postDataObj.endDt)}},
                {invitationId : {$in: postDataObj.invIds}}
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$sort": {logDate: 1 }},
     { $group: {
        _id: { 
            "invitationId":'$invitationId',
            "milestoneId":'$milestoneId',
            "activityId":  '$activityId'
        },
        invitationId : { $first : '$invitationId'},
        milestoneId : { $first : '$milestoneId'},
        activityId : { $first : '$activityId'},
        activityName : { $first : '$activityName'},
        logDate: {$first:'$logDate'},
        frequency1 : {$first: '$frequency1'},
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}         ],

{$cursor:{}}

).exec(function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    return res.jsonp(result);  });
```

=====================================================

This throws the following error...

> Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

...so I'm assuming I have the syntax of the added cursor element wrong somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla)

Comment: Update your mongoose version as mentioned in above dupe

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I had done an 'npm update mongoose' previously, but went back and did it again and realized the response I'm getting is:           

trunk\node_modules>npm update mongoose
mongoose@3.8.40 mongoose
└── ms@0.1.0



                 I should be getting to version 5.x according to the documentation, so I'll keep digging into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from the array and call it outside (right before exec)
Here is the updated code:

```
    ParticipantActivityLog.aggregate([
        {   $match: {
                "$and": [
                    {logDate :{$gte : new Date(postDataObj.strtDt),$lt : new Date(postDataObj.endDt)}},
                    {invitationId : {$in: postDataObj.invIds}}
                ]
            }
        },
        { "$sort": {logDate: 1 }},
         { $group: {
            _id: { 
                "invitationId":'$invitationId',
                "milestoneId":'$milestoneId',
                "activityId":  '$activityId'
            },
            invitationId : { $first : '$invitationId'},
            milestoneId : { $first : '$milestoneId'},
            activityId : { $first : '$activityId'},
            activityName : { $first : '$activityName'},
            logDate: {$first:'$logDate'},
            frequency1 : {$first: '$frequency1'},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}         ]

    )
.cursor({})
.exec(function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        return res.jsonp(result);  });
```

You specify the cursor options like this (if you want):

```
.cursor({ batchSize: 2500, async: true })
```