# mongoose concat and single element from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is a two part mongoDB/mongoose question

I want to concat a First Name/Last Name into "name" AND I only want to show the single "current" item from an array.

So if my data looks like this

```
[{
    "fname":"bob",
    "lname":"jones",
    "role":"professional", 
    "active":true,
    "jobs":[{
        "job":"janitor",
        "current":true
    },{
        "job":"dog groomer"
        "current":false
    }]
},{
    "fname":"sally",
    "lname":"peterson",
    "role":"professional", 
    "active":true,
    "jobs":[{
        "job":"engineer",
        "current":false
    },{
        "job":"college admin"
        "current":true
    }]
},{
    "fname":"jackson",
    "lname":"smiley",
    "role":"professional", 
    "active":true,
    "jobs":[{
        "job":"car salesman",
        "current":false
    },{
        "job":"street sweeper"
        "current":false
    }{
        "job":"house painter"
        "current":true
    }]
},{
    "fname":"katie",
    "lname":"smiley",
    "role":"amature", 
    "active":true,
    "jobs":[{
        "job":"drone entheuast",
        "current":true
    }]
}]
```

And I want my return data to be

```
[{
    name:"bob jones", 
    job:"janitor"
},{
    name:"sally peterson", 
    job:"college admin"},
{
    name:"jackson smiley", 
    job:"house painter"
}]
```

Currently - I am using this mongoose syntax - but it's not enough...

```
module.exports.getActiveList = function( callback ) {
        const query = { "role":"professional", "active":true }
        People.find( query, 'name job', callback );
    }
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

You can use [**`$concat`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to combine both `fname` and `lname` as a `name` and [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to obtain current active job from the `jobs` array

```
People.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "role": "professional", "active": true }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": { "$concat": ["$fname", " ", "$lname"] },
    "jobs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$jobs",
        "as": "job",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$job.current", true] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "name": 1, "job": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$jobs.job", 0] }}}
])
```

Or using [**`$let`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to complete in a single stage

```
People.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "role": "professional", "active": true }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": { "$concat": ["$fname", " ", "$lname"] },
    "job": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "jobs": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$jobs",
              "as": "job",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$job.current", true] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$jobs.job", 0] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Anthony, thank you for your time. I've modified my question a bit, because I don't know how the aggregation syntax fits in with the query filter syntax..see above question modifications

Comment: I am trying your suggestions now

Comment: ok great... I have updated the answer according to your question

Comment: hum - I get this error - MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument -- also can you explain what "$arrayElemAt": ["$$jobs.job", 0] is doing...

Comment: Here is your first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla... and the [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) takes the indexed element from the array (the second argument is for index)

Comment: Excellent - after getting my mongoose updated to 5.2.13 - all seems to be working. thank you - is there a performance/resource difference between your two examples?

Comment: if I want to project other elements form the person object - (using your first example) would I just add to the second $project, and use a $fieldname - so say I wanted the role to come back too - would the second $project be:  { "$project": { "name": 1, "job": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$jobs.job", 0] }, "role":"$role"}} ??

Comment: The second example will be quite better then the first one because it uses single stage to produce the expected output.